# python - define class structure for given input json

Tags: python, json, class, parsing, object

I have a json which has 2 different type of sub-structure depending on the value of field "source". The sample json is as follows:

```
{
  "abc": "abc1",
  "value": [
    {
      "source": "s1",
      "value": [
        {
          "name": "n1",
          "value": [
            {
              "value": "v1"
            },
            {
              "value": "v2"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "source": "s2",
      "value": [
        {
          "h1": "...",
          "h2": [
            {
              "h3": "..."
            },
            {
              "h3": "..."
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have written partial/incomplete code to parse it with jsonstruct:

```
import json

import jsonstruct

def parse_json_obj(json_obj):
    json_str = json.dumps(json_obj)
    return jsonstruct.decode(json_str, ABCData)

class Entry(object):
    name = ""
    value = ""

class NameData(object):
    name = ""
    value = [Entry()]

class SourceData(object):
    source = ""
    value = [NameData()]

class ABCData(object):
    abc = ""
    value = [SourceData()]


a = parse_json_obj(<json_data_above>)
print a.value[0].source                # prints s1
print a.value[0].value[0].value[0].value       # prints v1
```

Now I am stuck to how to extend it to incorporate another source type (s2) sub-structure. Any help in any direction would be super useful. Thanks !

Comment: any particular reason you're using jsonstruct? it seems to be a less than complete project that is a fork of [jsonpickle](http://jsonpickle.github.io/)

Comment: @csunday95, umm.. no particular reason, found this as first thing. So how to do it in jsonpickle ?